# Help with downloading SPO files in folder structure based on metadata

Tags: sharepoint-online, power-automate, document-set, download, file-metadata

I have a SPO libary with document-sets, in which multiple documents are stored.
Every docset is linked to an 'Object' (metadata).
Every document inside a docset has metadata 'Document type'.
The documents need to move from SPO to a USB-drive, but I do not want to lose the Object and Document-type structuring.

**I want to create an automated solution to download documents inside a new-to-create folder structure, based on the names of attached metadata**: For each Object a separate folder, and inside these Object-folders, folders for every 'Document type' available. Inside the latter, the actual documents need to be placed.
(Creating the folders and copying the files to a OneDrive is also sufficient.)

It looks like a multiple step problem:

- Search for docsets with metadata 'Object', and create 1 folder for every object in the list.
- Search for documents with metadata 'Document type', that are inside a docset with metadata 'Object', and create folders for each 'Document type' within the 'Object' folder (made in the previous step).
- Copy all files with metadata 'Document type' within a docset with 'Object' metadata, to their destined location.

Who has experience with such a problem and what would be the most fitting strategy Power Automate functions to achieve the automation?

Thanks in advance